# Trying to duplicate a Bash script into ansible -- Not sure how to best handle alternatives with Slaves

Tags: bash, ansible

I see there was a feature request for this, but they do not note how they actually worked around it. In a nutshell, we download a groovy archive, unzip it, and create slaves for every file in the archive that is not the groovy executable, and doesnt end with .bat. We then do a update-alternatives for groovy.

```
GROOVY_ALT_SLAVES=""
for f in $(ls /opt/groovy-${GROOVY_VERSION}/bin | fgrep -v .bat | grep -v '^groovy$'); do
    GROOVY_ALT_SLAVES=" ${GROOVY_ALT_SLAVES}  --slave /usr/bin/${f} ${f} /opt/groovy-${GROOVY_VERSION}/bin/${f}"
done

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/groovy groovy /opt/groovy-${GROOVY_VERSION}/bin/groovy 2000 ${GROOVY_ALT_SLAVES}
update-alternatives --set groovy /opt/groovy-${GROOVY_VERSION}/bin/groovy
```

I cant really wrap my head around the best way to dupe this, that isnt just running the shell module.  Once I resigned myself to using the shell module, I then read that doing something like

```
 - shell: GROOVY_ALT_SLAVES=" ${GROOVY_ALT_SLAVES}  --slave /usr/bin/{{ item }} {{ item }} /opt/groovy-{{ groovy_version }}/bin/{{ item }}"
   with_items: ['file1', 'file2']
```

Wouldn't work, since each shell run is a separate connection, so Im not really building up a long string to then append to the update-alternatives command.  There is also the fact I have to manually specify a list of items, since I cant use glob because i need to match files that do not match a certain set of expressions.

Im sure Im missing something obvious, but I haven't made any progress on this one and any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Make your string inside a playbook and execute shell only once.

Something like this:

```
- shell: update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/groovy groovy /opt/groovy-{{ groovy_version }}/bin/groovy 2000 {{ alt_slaves }}
  vars:
    alt_slaves: "{{ myfiles | map('regex_replace','(.*)','--slave /usr/bin/\1 \1 /opt/groovy-'+groovy_version+'/bin/\1') | list | join(' ') }}
```

I didn't test this, you may have to play with escaping `\1` to make it work.

Comment: Can you explain this section.       

alt_slaves: "{{ myfiles | map('regex_replace','(.*)','--slave /usr/bin/\1 \1 /opt/groovy-'+groovy_version+'/bin/\1') | list | join(' ') }}

Comment: We calculate `alt_slaves` var as follows: take `myfiles` list, apply `regex_replace` filter to every item of the list with specified regexp (which forms required slave string where `\1` is an item from original list), then join all the items together with space as delimiter.